# ListView performance lower on 4.2 than on 4.1

Tags: android, performance, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I have just upgraded on Android 4.2 on my Galaxy Nexus and ListView seems to be slower than It used to be on 4.1. This bindView method was perfect fast on 4.1, on new 4.2 I see small glitches. I have tried to explicitly enable hardware acceleration in `AndroidManifest.xml`, but it dit not help much. People (Contacts) app works perfect on 4.2, which I guess is also implemented by extended `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter`. I have also already tried to change `android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter` for `android.widget.CursorAdapter` without visible improvement.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.nameView.setText(cursor.getString(mStreetColumnIndex));
    holder.townView.setText(cursor.getString(mTownColumnIndex));
    if (mDistanceColumn != null) {
        float distance = cursor.getFloat(mDistanceColumn);
        String distanceUnit;
        if (distance >= 1000) {
            distance /= 1000;
            distanceUnit = " km";
        } else {
            distanceUnit = " m";
        }
        String decimalString = mDecimalFormat.format(distance);
        holder.distanceView.setText(decimalString + distanceUnit);
        holder.distanceView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.distanceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // read only brand first letter to be faster
    cursor.copyStringToBuffer(mBrandColumnIndex, mBuffer);
    if (mBuffer.sizeCopied > 0) {
        if (mBuffer.data[0] == 'a') {
            holder.logoImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.agip);
        } else {
            holder.logoImgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.papoil);
        }
    } else {
        holder.logoImgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

EDIT: added row layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/row_height"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_list_selector"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_padding"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/screen_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/screen_padding">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_padding"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txtDistance"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_primary_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTown"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_text_primary_size"
            />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDistance"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_dark"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/screen_padding"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/agip"
        android:background="@color/grey_dark"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2: 
here is traceview http://goo.gl/UmS3w
which was made using http://goo.gl/Yoe1u

Comment: I have added row layout.

Comment: is there a line under your textviews?

Comment: Yes, defined using `<item name="android:divider">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_light</item>`

Comment: no, I mean a line directly under the textviews, I had this problem in 4.2 where some kind of spellchecking was enabled in my textviews , i just added this to every textview and the listview was fast again.        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Comment: You should know that since you're using a `CursorAdapter`, the `newView()` method where you inflate the `Views` already implements some sort of `ViewHolder` pattern in it's source code. You don't need to add your own `ViewHolder`.

Comment: Can you set LinearLayout's android:layout_width="match_parent". If this does not improve or improves little try others as well.

Comment: @auselen Thanks, I tried and It didn't help.

Comment: @tolgap Thanks, I removed it, but it didn't increase performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was caused by too much complicated windowBackground, which was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_repeat">
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#0affffff" android:endColor="#0a000000"
                  android:type="radial" android:gradientRadius="500"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient android:startColor="#1effffff" android:endColor="#1e000000"
                  android:type="linear" android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

and bg_repeat.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Thanks all for help!